# Difference between using "./" as a prefix for url and not using it on node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm learning about nodeJs, and I'm curious about the differences between using "./some-file-url" and "some-file-url" as an url path in nodeJs?

Comment: The second is rather a module id, while the first is an actual path

Comment: @dim so if i want to access a file on a same folder directory, both url work the same?

Comment: no, use the first one

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky okay, thanks for the answear! this is my first time asking on stack overflow